# UIPopoverController with navigation bar inconsistent on device and simulator

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have a simple popover for a UINavigationController that is anchored on the root views right bar button item. On the iPhone simulator (I tried it on various devices) the navigation bar of the popover aligns nicely with the navigation bar of the root view. I assume this is taken care of by UIKit. Here is a screenshot of the simulator.

[image]

However on my physical device there is a slight offset. This is a screenshot on my iPhone 6 physical device. It's weird because there's no offset for the iPhone 6 simulation. Notice they bottoms of the navigation bars are not aligned.

[image]

I couldn't find any stack overflow questions addressing this and I'm not sure how to fix it since all we're "supposed" to do is specify the popover anchor (as the plus button) and let UIKit take care of the rest. Is there any way to fix this programmatically? I'm not using storyboards or xibs. I also have touch assist enabled on my physical device.

Comment: It would help if you showed the result of running on an iPhone 6 simulator instead of comparing your iPhone 6 device to the iPhone X simulator.

Comment: Edit: Post now shows iPhone 6 screenshot simulation instead of iPhone X

Comment: @DaltonSweeney By physically mapping the 2 screenshots, I can see that the navbar height of the screen seems to be different in both the screenshots. It seems to be around 3 pixels of difference, not sure of the reason for this. However, the popover is placed properly. Could you recheck the OS versions and the possible issue for height difference?

Comment: My device is iOS version 11.2.6 and the simulator is 11.2